# Strikethrough lines in minted

Tags: minted, strikeout

I want to strikethrough some line in a minted enviroment, for example line 3 in

```
\documentclass[usenames,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]

\begin{minted}[linenos, numbersep=3pt]{python}
# This program prints Hello, world!

print('Hello, world!')
\end{minted}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]